# How to request a POST API send token and body values using Rest-Assured?

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured

I'm trying to create an Test Automation for a POST API using Rest-Assured and Java.
This POST API have a body as Application/JSON, like this:

```
{
    "customer":{
        "email": "teste@mailinator.com"
    },
    "password":"Teste@12"
}
```

To make this request I'm using the follow code, but it's returning Status code "400", but I'm sending the same information on Postman and it's returning "200":

```
@And("envio as informacoes da chamada: (.*), (.*), (.*), (.*) e (.*)")
        public void enviarDados (String srtEmail, String srtSenha, String srtAmbiente, String srtAPI, String srtToken) {
HashMap<String,String> postContent = new HashMap<String,String>();
            postContent.put("email", srtEmail);
            postContent.put("password", srtSenha);
            //System.out.println("{\"customer\":" +postContent+ "}");
            given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).header("Authorization", "Bearer"+srtToken).header("Content-Type", "application/json").
            //with().body(postContent).
            with().body("{\"customer\":" +postContent+ "}").
            when().post(srtAmbiente+srtAPI).
            then().statusCode(200); 
}
```

The "400" response is:

```
{
"status": 400,
"message": "Malformed request",
"additional_error": ""
}
```

Comment: Is there any error message with 400 code?

Comment: Could you add response body for 400 code? You can print response by adding .prettyPeek() after .post(srtAmbiente+srtAPI)

Comment: Also you don't need to add Content-Type header since you have since you've already specified it here .contentType(ContentType.JSON)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending an incorrect body with POST.

```
//This line will not serialize HashMap to JSON, but call toString()
.body("{\"customer\":" +postContent+ "}")
```

As a result your payload will look this way:

> {"customer":{password=password, customer=example@example.com}}

which is not a valid JSON.
Try this:

```
Map<String, String> emailContent = new HashMap<>();
emailContent.put("email", "example@example.com");
Map<String, Object> postContent = new HashMap<>();
postContent.put("customer", emailContent);
postContent.put("password", "password");
given().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+srtToken)
    .with().body(postContent)
    .when().post(srtAmbiente+srtAPI)
    .then().statusCode(200);
```

Comment: You can also use JSONObject instead of Map - https://pastebin.com/V1cx727C